# A possible characterization of all generalized inverses of a matrix

Tags: matrices, generalized-inverse

> If $G$ is a generalized inverse of a matrix $A$ (i.e. $AGA=A$), then is it true that every generalized inverse of $A$ can be written in the form $G+B-GABAG$ for some matrix $B$ of same order as $G$?

I could show that this matrix is a generalized inverse for every matrix $B$, since
\begin{align}
A(G+B-GABAG)A&=AGA+ABA-AGABAGA\\
&=A+ABA-ABA\\
&=A
\end{align}
But I couldn't conclude that every generalized inverse of $A$ can be written in this form. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(X)=AXA,\,g(X)=GAXAG$ and $\pi=\operatorname{id}-g$. One can verify that $g$ and in turn $\pi$ are idempotent. Also, $f\pi=0$. Therefore
$$
\operatorname{range}(\pi)\subseteq\ker(f)\subseteq\ker(g).
$$
However, as $\pi$ is $g$ are complementary projections to each other, we have $\operatorname{range}(\pi)=\ker(g)$. Thus $\operatorname{range}(\pi)=\ker(f)=\ker(g)$ by the sandwich principle.

Now, for any generalised inverse $X$ of $A$, we have $X-G\in\ker(f)=\operatorname{range}(\pi)$. Hence $X=G+\pi(B)$ for some matrix $B$.

Comment: I didn't quite follow the idea of complementary projections. I understand this for the case of linear functions, i.e. $h(X)=PX$ for some vector matrix $P$. Then $rank(P)+rank(I-P) = tr(P)+tr(I-P)=tr(I)=n$. Hence by rank nullity theorem $rank(P)=nullity(I-P)$ and vice versa. I don't see how are you generalizing this thing.

Comment: @Martund Complementary projections are just two projections that sum to the identity operator. In the present context it just means $\pi+g=\operatorname{id}$.

Comment: Yes that I understood. I don't understand what do mean by rank of that function, since that is not a matrix anymore, and how are you applying rank nullity theorem?

Comment: @Martund I was talking about the rank of a linear map. Anyway, in hindsight, the dimension argument is unnecessary. Since $\pi$ and $g$ are complementary projections, $\operatorname{range}(\pi)=\ker(g)$ follows.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!